# can Django serialize a Json with unknown lists and dicts?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Json file that I receive and I would like to serialize it using Django. However, I do not always know what fields will be included in the Json. Some of these Json files will include noted lists and nested dicts. Is there a way to use Django serializer in order to serialize all of the fields or do I have to specify each field name as well as the type of object that it is?

Comment: You can send arbitrary json with [`api_view`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)  You can receive arbitrary json by looking at [`request.data`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects)